# DropDownList Items in List

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me shortest way to add all items of dropdownlist in a `List<string>`

I want to populate a `List<string>` with the values of a DropDownList

Comment: what language and what framework?  are you on 3.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends if you want the ListItem Text and you are able to leverage 3.5

```
public static List<string> GetStrings(DropDownList dl)
{
    return dl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Seems like the only other answer which shows how to add items TO the List, from the DDL. +1

Comment: i love how clean linq makes things, :)

Answer (score 3):

Your post was a little unclear are you adding items to the drop down list or to the list?

To add to the list:
var list = new List(DropDownList.Items.Length);

```
foreach(var item in DropDownList.Items.Length)
   list.Add(item.Text);
```

To Add to the drop down list:

```
var list = new List<string> ();
    DropDownList.DataSource = list;
    DropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Seems like the only other answer which shows how to add items TO the List, from the DDL. +1

Answer (score 2):

yep. Set the datasource to the List<string>

Answer (score 1):

```
myDropDown.DataSource = myListOfStrings;
myDropDown.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:
ddl your dropdown list.
ListOfStrings your list of strings.

This should work:

```
foreach (var str in ListOfStrings)
{
  ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(str, str);
}
```