# Best way to check if a drop down list contains a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

When the user navigates to a new page, this ddl's selected index is determined by a cookie, but if the ddl doesn't contain that cookie's value, then I'd like it to be set the 0. What method would I use for the ddl? Is a loop the best way, or is there a simply if statement I can perform?

This is what I've attempted, but it doesn't return a bool.

```
if ( !ddlCustomerNumber.Items.FindByText( GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString() ) )
    ddlCustomerNumber.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

There are two methods that come to mind:

You could use Contains like so:

```
if (ddlCustomerNumber.Items.Contains(new 
    ListItem(GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString())))
{
    // ... code here
}
```

or modifying your current strategy:

```
if (ddlCustomerNumber.Items.FindByText(
    GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString()) != null)
{
    // ... code here
}
```

EDIT:  There's also a `DropDownList.Items.FindByValue` that works the same way as FindByText, except it searches based on values instead.

Comment: The first `Contains` didn't work for me. Even if the item exists in the dropdown `ListItemCollection`, it went to the `else` condition. Any idea why?

Comment: Missing references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue

Answer (score 9):

That will return an item. Simply change to:

```
if (ddlCustomerNumber.Items.FindByText( GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString()) != null)
    ddlCustomerNumber.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: There is no .Count available.

Comment: A collection of items or one single item? I don't know asp.net but Google suggested that it (ListItemCollection.FindByText) returns a ListItem or null? So != null it would be?

Comment: Sorry, I realized my mistake right after posting, but apparently not before I confused a couple people... I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 5):

If 0 is your default value, you can just use a simple assignment:

```
ddlCustomerNumber.SelectedValue = GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString();
```

This automatically selects the proper list item, if the DDL contains the value of the cookie. If it doesn't contain it, this call won't change the selection, so it stays at the default selection. If the latter one is the same as value 0, then it's the perfect solution for you.

I use this mechanism quite a lot and find it very handy.

Comment: But if it doesn't contain it during a PostBack, it throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_SelectedValue

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
ListItem match = ddlCustomerNumber.Items.FindByText(
    GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString());
if (match == null)
    ddlCustomerNumber.SelectedIndex = 0;
//else
//    match.Selected = true; // you'll probably select that cookie value
```

Answer (score 1):

On C# this works:

```
        if (DDLAlmacen.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (DDLAlmacen.Items.FindByValue("AlmacenDefectoAndes").Value == "AlmacenDefectoAndes")
            {
                DDLAlmacen.SelectedValue = "AlmacenDefectoAndes";
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

Translating the code above to Visual Basic doesn't work. It throws "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.."

So. for this to work on Visual Basic, I had to change the code like this:

```
        If DDLAlmacen.Items.Count > 0 Then
            If DDLAlmacen.Items.Contains(New ListItem("AlmacenDefectoAndes")) Then
                DDLAlmacen.SelectedValue = "AlmacenDefectoAndes"
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: `DDLAlmacen.Items.FindByValue("AlmacenDefectoAndes").Value == "AlmacenDefectoAndes"`should be `DDLAlmacen.Items.FindByValue("AlmacenDefectoAndes") != null`, otherwise you get the NullReferenceException if it can't find an entry with that value.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListItem item = ddlComputedliat1.Items.FindByText("Amt D");
if (item == null) {
    ddlComputedliat1.Items.Insert(1, lblnewamountamt.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking to see if this method returns a null:

```
if (ddlCustomerNumber.Items.FindByText(GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString()) != null)
    ddlCustomerNumber.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

//you can use the ? operator instead of if

```
ddlCustomerNumber.SelectedValue = ddlType.Items.FindByValue(GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString()) != null ? GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString() : "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function return Nothing, you can try this below

```
if (ddlCustomerNumber.Items.FindByText(
    GetCustomerNumberCookie().ToString()) != Nothing)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the value needs to be trimmed of whitespace or it won't be matched, in such case this additional step can be used ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143178/10634638)):

```
if(((DropDownList) myControl1).Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Value.Trim() == ctrl.value.Trim()).FirstOrDefault() != null){}
```