# cannot set the text of dropdown list in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

This is my code for populating my dropdown list:

```
For i = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(count1)
            etc.CommandText = "select Classification from schemaItemDetails.AssetCategory where ASC_ID = " & i & ""
            Dim dra1 As SqlDataReader = etc.ExecuteReader
            While (dra1.Read())
                ddonecategory.Items.Add(dra1.GetString(0))
            End While
            dra1.Close()
        Next
```

How can I set the text of my dropdownlist? becauase when I use this code to set the text of the dropdown list:

```
ddonecategory.Text = "Toolings".Text
```

I am getting this kind of error:

```
'ddonecategory' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code. Are you writing this in WebForms?

Comment: And what are the issues with my code?

Comment: To begin with, `"Toolings".Text` is not valid code

Comment: Is there a reason you are populating your dropdownlist this way? I typically use a DataSource when possible, but even if you want to do it in code behind, using a `for` loop with a SqlDataReader is not advisable.

Comment: @probackpacker -  ahh yes sorry for my mistake, it'actually "Toolings" only. Ah ok sir, I don't know about datasource sorry I'm a newbie, anyway thanks sir I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to write in vb but in C# it should be like this

```
   ddonecategory.SelectedIndex = 
               ddonecategory.Items.IndexOf(ddonecategory.Items.FindByText("Your value"));
```

The key is `Items.FindByText` method 
The benefit of this is if the item is not found it is set to -1.
So there will not be any error if there is no matching found in the dropdown list.

### Edit -1

Here is a good explanation 
[Best way to check if a drop down list contains a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007203/best-way-to-check-if-a-drop-down-list-contains-a-value)

### Edit 2

Here is the VB code

```
 Dim searchString As String = "Toolings".Text
 If ddonecategory.Items.FindByText(searchString) IsNot Nothing Then
     Label1.Text = "Item Found: " & searchString
 Else
     Label1.Text = "Item not Found: " & searchString
 End If
```