# DropDownList with a SelectedValue that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a table which populates a dropdownlist called DropDownList_Tracking_Status.  The table has 3 columns; ID, TrackingName and Active.  When I fill the dropdownlist, I pull every record where Active = "Y".

When I'm reading data into the form, I'm trying to pre-select the appropriate value for DropDownList_Tracking_Status.  If the current status is empty (one hasn't been chosen yet), I set it equal to 2.  Otherwise, I set it equal to whatever value was previously selected.  The problem I have is, if the current Tracking Status is a status that's since been marked as inactive (where Active was set to "N"), it throws an error.  Obviously, because it can't pre-select a value that doesn't exist in the dropdownlist.

Any ideas on how to solve this?  My current code block looks like this:

```
if ((DT["TrackingStatus"].ToString() == ""))
{
   DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = "2";
}
else
{
   DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = (DT["TrackingStatus"].ToString());
}
```

**EDIT**
I'm just going to add that the table that populates the dropdownlist is the one that contains the Active field.  The SqlDataReader called DT does not have that field in it.  I suppose I could create a query that joins the two and checks the value of Active, but I was hoping there was an easier way.  Something that says (in pseudo-code):

```
If DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = (DT["TrackingStatus"].ToString()); throws you an error, do this instead...
```

Comment: `DT` is a `DataRow`? What error is thrown?

Comment: if your table have just 2 row? then it's threw the error.

Comment: Why dont you check current Tracking Status before this logic and if it doesnt exist in the dropDown but needs to be then add it?

Comment: The problem is that the Active field is in the table that contains the list of all possible Tracking Statuses.  DT is a SqlDataReader.  It's reading the table that has the actual data, so I don't know how I'd reference it without using another data reader.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the code in `try-catch` block as,

```
try
{
 DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = DT["TrackingStatus"].ToString();
}
catch
{
 DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = "2";
}
```

It will bind the value if it exists otherwise it will through exception, on which you can asign any default value in `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following possible (possibly preceeded by a check for a null record):

```
if ((DT["TrackingStatus"].ToString() == ""))
{
   DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = "2"; 
}
else if(DT["Active"] == "N")
{
    DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = "2"; 
}
else
{
   DropDownList_Tracking_Status.SelectedValue = (DT["TrackingStatus"].ToString());
}
```

**UPDATE**
Adding the Active field to DT seems a good solution OR an alternative would be to see if the dropdown list contains the target value. See the Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007203/best-way-to-check-if-a-drop-down-list-contains-a-value)

Comment: The problem is that the Active field is in the table that contains the list of all possible Tracking Statuses.  DT is a SqlDataReader.  It's reading the table that has the actual data, so I don't know how I'd reference it without using another data reader.